# upload a file to the target folder based on the categories defined

Tags: html, jsp, multipartform-data

i want to upload a file to the specified folder based on the categories defined in the drop-down list.i have used o'reilly api to upload files which will store the files to a single loaction.i have used 2 dropdowns (main category and sub category).if user has defined his option,then the path should change and the file should be uploaded to the specified folder eg:"c:\output\aero\int".the path will be dynamic and will change based on user input.my code to upload file

```
<%@page import="javax.ejb.DuplicateKeyException"%>
<%@ page   import="java.io.*,java.sql.*,java.util.zip.*,com.oreilly.servlet.*,com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%
 ResultSet rs=null;

Connection connection = null;
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ksa";
PreparedStatement psmnt = null;
    PreparedStatement psmnt1=null;
    PreparedStatement psmnt2=null;
    String path;
    path="/home/adapco/Desktop/output";
    MultipartRequest request2=new MultipartRequest(request,path,1024*1024*1024);

String filename=request2.getFilesystemName("file");
String file1=request2.getParameter("file1");
String selectedValue=request2.getParameter("sel1");
String select1=request2.getParameter("sel2");
String concat=selectedValue+"." +select1;
File f=request2.getFile("file");
//out.println(f.exists()+"----------------"+f.getAbsolutePath());
//out.print(filename);

  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

 connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");
 try
 {  

  java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());

  psmnt1 = connection.prepareStatement("insert into   file12(id,file_description,file_path,file_date) values(?,?,?,'"+ sqlDate+"')");

  psmnt1.setString(1, concat);
  psmnt1.setString(2, file1);
  psmnt1.setString(3, f.getPath());
  //psmnt.setString(3, "sqlDate");
 //String query="select * from file12";
  int s=psmnt1.executeUpdate();
  if(s>0)
  {
 System.out.println("Uploaded successfully !");
 }
 else
  {
 System.out.println("Error!");
 }
 psmnt=connection.prepareStatement("select * from file12");
 rs=psmnt.executeQuery();
 }

 catch(Exception e)
 {
 out.print(" the file already exist"+e);
 }

 %>
 <table cellpadding="15" border="1">
 <%
  while(rs.next()){
  %>
 <tr>
<td><%=rs.getString(1)%> </td>
<td><%=rs.getString(2)%> </td>
<td><%=rs.getString(3)%> </td>
<td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
</tr>
<%}%>
 <a href="index.jsp">home</a><br>
  <a href="sample.jsp">upload file</a>
 </table>
 <%
 response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
 %>
```

the design part with dropdowns:

```
<FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="sample2.jsp" METHOD=POST>
<center>
 <table bgcolor=#38ACEC>
 <tr>
  <center><td colspan="2" align="center"><B>UPLOAD THE FILE</B><center></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"> </td></tr>
 <tr><td><b>Choose the file To Upload:</b></td>
 <td><INPUT NAME="file" TYPE="file"></td>
   </tr>
  <!--<tr><td><b>Choose the destination folder:</b></td>
   <td><INPUT NAME="file1" TYPE="file"></td>
  </tr>-->
   <tr><td><select name="sel1">
 <option value="1">Aerospace</option>
 <option value="2">Automotive</option>
 <option value="3">Energy</option>
 <option value="4">IC Engines</option>
 <option value="5">Wind</option>
 <option value="6">Turbo</option>
 <option value="7">IT</option>
 <option value="8">Training</option>
 </select>
 <br>
 <select name="sel2">
 <option value="1">Internal</option>
 <option value="2">Demos</option>
 <option value="3">Best Practice</option>
 <option value="4">Marketing</option>
 <option value="5">Papers & public</option>
 <option value="6">Validation</option>
 <option value="7">Training</option>
 </select></td></tr>
 <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"> </td></tr>
 <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Send File"> </td></tr>
 </table>
 </center>
 </form>
```

what iam trying to do is :

```
 MultipartRequest request2=new MultipartRequest(request,"/home/adapco/Desktop/output",1024*1024*1024);

String filename=request2.getFilesystemName("file");
String file1=request2.getParameter("file1");
String selectedValue=request2.getParameter("sel1");
String select1=request2.getParameter("sel2");
String concat=selectedValue+"." +select1;
File f=request2.getFile("file");
//out.println(f.exists()+"----------------"+f.getAbsolutePath());
//out.print(filename);
Double double1=Double.parseDouble(concat);
if(double1==1.1)
           {
                request2=new MultipartRequest(request,"/home/adapco/Desktop/output/aero/int",1024*1024*1024);
           }
```

the above code shows me error

```
  java.io.IOException: Corrupt form data: premature ending
```

if the multipart object alone  is created it shows me

```
  request2 is not initialized.
```

i am comparing the concatenation values in order to get the user defined categories.

Comment: What have you tried ? I don't see any code which shows your efforts.Do you want SO users to write the code for you ?

Comment: @HardikMishra: i have define what iam trying todo

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to upload file with specific folder name .

step 1. submit your form using ajax request and post parameter using url that you are using folder creation.
Example:

```
var url ="test?folder1=f1&folder2=f2"
$('form').attr('action',url);
```

after submit form using ajax or javascript form.submit;

and read the folder name on `request.getParameter('folder1'),request.getParameter('folder2')`

It is working fine.